# Creating an Open ID Connect Provider (provider metadata)

Tags: php, openid-connect

I'm attempting to create an open id connect provider using the library:
[bshaffer/oauth2-server-php](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php)

Then connect to it using:
jumbojett/openid-connect-php

Ive got to the point where i'm looking at /.well-known/openid-configuration. I can't find any information regarding this - how to write it - what to put in it - what the different areas are for. And especially the jwks_keys section, which is required to verify the id_tokens that are returned.

Has anyone got any information on how to implement this or got anywhere regarding it?

The problem i'm getting is the error 'Cannot verify signature'

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: You're looking for the discovery part of OIDC: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderMetadata

Comment: Thanks pieter, you are right thats exactly what i'm after.... next question if you can help though is how do you generate the jwks_keys section? I feel like i'm missing a part of the puzzle that connects it all together.

Comment: Just for your information, I have a project to provide such feature. It is not yet stqble, but I expect to release it by the end of the year. See https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/oauth2-server-library for more information.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately i don't have quite that long :)

Comment: Have you got the solution? Please help

Comment: @AbdulJabbar what about you? Did you find any solution?

Comment: @John No, I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

For a description of the `/.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint, look at the [OIDC Discovery specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderMetadata).

This spec also mentions the `jwks_keys` (or rather `jwks_uri`?) attribute, which is a (reference to a) list of the public signing and encryption keys the OIDC Provider might use, formatted as a [JWK Set](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-5).

Clients wanting to verify an ID Token issued by your provider will extract the `kid` from the ID Token's JWT Header, and use that to look up the correct signing key in the discovered `jwks_uri`. Hence your Provider is allowed to use more than one key, for key rotation, or in general.

Comment: `jwks_uri` is the correct one, not sure where I got jwks_keys from... I read the same description, just dont' really understand what it wants me to do, how do I get a list of the public signing and encryption keys?

Comment: If the server you reference doesn't support hits, then you would need to check how it manages these keys internally and then expose them as a JWK Set. Maybe submit a patch.

Comment: Have you got the solution. Please help?

Comment: Sorry no, I never got to the solution. I literally just went down to the cognito method in Aws and removed the current login scripts

Comment: So, haven't you setup your own OIDC provider and then used it for authentication ?